# joomla custom search plugin not showing results but return object

Tags: search, plugins, joomla

I'm making a custom component for joomla 3.1 and I've followed this tutorial => http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_search_plugin (I had to make many changes but in the end it worked).

..The object returned by my custom plugin looks like core content plugin of joomla, but the problem is that the results are not displayed in search results screen... what I'm doing wrong?

this is the object that the plugin return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [title] => Test
            [metadesc] => 
            [metakey] => 
            [created] => 2013-06-05 16:10:14
            [text] => some text here
            [section] => Test
            [slug] => 8:test
            [catslug] => 11:test
            [browsernav] => 2
            [href] => index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=8:test&catid=11:test&Itemid=xxx
        )

)
```

Await for some anwsers!

Regards!

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Can you be more specific.

Comment: Post full source code to find the issue.

Comment: I cannot add images yet but you can see in this url:
 
http://joomla30.cloudaccess.net/component/search/?searchword=joom&ordering=newest&searchphrase=all

The results of my plugin doesn't showing in search results at bottom, but the object is returned by my plugin function.

Comment: is no a code issue I guess, and cannot put my code. 
But you can see the content plugin in joomla plugins folder, is the same code only modificated for my purposes and to use other db tables. I Insist.. that the plugin is returning the object in the same way it does the joomla content plugin but joomla not returning result at all in view.